# How to save variable data as .json extension file format in a specific file location using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, save

I have a variable with data

```
var str = [
{"khewat_no":"390","Column1":"ਜਸਮੇਲ ਸਿੰਘ ","owner_share":"36/181"}
,{"khewat_no":"390","Column1":"ਕੌਰ ","owner_share":"22/181"}
]
```

I want to save this data in a specific file location with a .json extension using jquery, please help me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: *This is how you can download it as JSON*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>abhi example</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


      $("#data").click(function() {
        var str = [{
          "khewat_no": "390",
          "Column1": "ਜਸਮੇਲ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸੋਹਣ ਸਿਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਿਸਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ",
          "owner_share": "50/151"
        }, {
          "khewat_no": "390",
          "Column1": "ਸੁਖਦੇਵ ਕੌਰ ਪਤਨੀ ਸੋਹਣ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਿਸ਼ਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ",
          "owner_share": "25/151"
        }]
        var j_obj = JSON.stringify(str[0]);
        $("<a />", {
            "download": "data.json",
            "href": "data:application/json," + encodeURIComponent(j_obj)
          }).appendTo("body")
          .click(function() {
            $(this).remove()
          })[0].click()
      })
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="data"> Click to download</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, sir for your response but I don't want to download the file, my question is how to save that content in a specific folder with the .json extension.

Comment: when you say save in a specific folder. Where is this folder, on server? or client machine?

Comment: on client machine